# Importing eclipse projects to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I'm trying to import an eclipse project to android studio but keep getting the error message:

```
Gradle 'PhotoGallery' project refresh failed:

Error:C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\2.14.1\scripts-remapped\settings_2yhllogm103q9sdcjkhbixdfg\9ejwtyixtds2dlx9q4hqm4iap\cp_settings57408229\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I've already tried the below, but the problem persists:

> File > Invalidate Caches/Restart > Invalidate and Restart

Here is a screenshot of the issue:
[image: Here is a picture of the issue]

Comment: Close and reopen the project. If it doesn't help, delete the gradle cache (.gradle/caches). It might take a while to download dependencies again.

Comment: You can delete the entire `C:\Users\user\.gradle` folder. It'll regenerate

Comment: Thanks guys this worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing  .gradle directory should resolve your problem because android studio will recreate gradle directory without an error.